# Interface example seems to have unnecessary extensions

Tags: java, interface

I have recently begun going back through the basics of OOP. I recently came across an example that I find somewhat confusing. If i am correct the following diagram appears to show 2 interfaces in which there are other interfaces that extend from them. The Payment interface and the Order interface. My Question being why is PaymentInterface and OrderInterface not enough. Why cant we just let the three client classes implement these 2 interfaces and implement the methods from each interface

```
public interface RestaurantInterface {
public  void acceptOnlineOrder();
public  void takeTelephoneOrder();
public  void payOnline();
public  void walkInCustomerOrder();
public  void payInPerson();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pedagogical examples are just that. Intended to help you learn the idea. Not necessarily indicative of best practices.

Comment: So are the extending interfaces necessary?

Comment: Did you learn the principle of *lean interfaces*? Define **necessary**?

Comment: Necessary in a Turing sense? No, extending (or implementing) interfaces is not necessary. Useful, yes, very.

Comment: Ok maybe a better quesiton, how in this case is the extending useful. How would i use this in a way that makes the implementation more flexible or useful

Comment: The issue could be one of terminology. In UML, saying `WalkInOrderImpl extends OrderInterface` means "it specializes", without specifying whether the specialization is logical (Java `interface`) or physical (Java `implements`). In other words, Java has 2 keyword: `extends` for interface-to-interface or class-to-class and `implements` for interface-to-class, UML has one keyword `extends` that is used in both cases.

Comment: Maybe I am misreading the UML diagram as I do not have much knowledge of them. Are the green rectangles classes? Also are the entities that are extending the interfaces supposed to be classes that implement the interfaces and if so what then are the TelephoneClient, WalkInClient, and OnlineClient?